# Get a post id from me/home

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

With Facebook Graph API (or FQL, it's not important), I retrieve me/home stream.
In result, I have a post, posted by me, on the wall of other; I have the post id of this post for "My" wall, but I want to retrieve the post id corresponding to this same post... On the friend wall. Do you understand what I mean? I'm not sur it is clear.

Anyone know how to do this? (with graph API ou FQL)

Thank you in advance
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to get the post id out of the stream you receive through graph API call (returns JSON object). You just have to parse the json.

Say for example you get the json as: data={
actions={
Id=274473838373_4848328282;
Message=This is my new status;
Object_id=838288282874;
...
...
}
}
Parse out the id and you are good to go.

I dont think you can get the post id appearing on your friends wall unless you are calling with his credentials which can't be done.

One thing i can think of is fetch the id of your friend and replace it with the number before underscore('_') in the id above. Just a wild guess.

But this id is enough to perform anything you want to do with the post.